# gRaphael Pie Chart : Add animation

Tags: raphael, graphael

I want to display the pie chart with an animation that will make it grow from a "small point" to full size pie chart , something like this [growing pie](http://raphaeljs.com/growing-pie.html) or this [Highcharts Demo Gallery - Pie](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) , but I want to apply it to a pie made with gRaphael ,

Here's my jsfiddle example... [raphael pie chart with legend](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/85VtZ/3/)

Thanks ahead,

Comment: stackoverflow is not a "gimme the codez" kinda website. [did you try anything](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: so please state it in the question. you're not likely to get useful answers without showing some research effort.

Comment: suit yourself. i'm trying to help, but it's hard to do with so little information.

Comment: All I'm looking for a way display the chart with animation , I thought that for an average g raphael user it would be peanuts... (my graphael knowledge are poor)... I guess I was wrong, Thanks anyway

Comment: do you mean something along the lines of [that](http://jsfiddle.net/85VtZ/7/)? click on the pie to see the action. of course there are several issues with it, but it's a starting point - try fiddling about with it and see what you can come up with.

Comment: @EliranMalka thanks , Ronin posted exactly what I was after...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to achieve that kind of animation you have to access the sectors and... animate them :)

You can do this using your_pie.each()

```
pie.each(function(){
  //scale each sector to 0
  this.sector.scale(0, 0, this.cx, this.cy);
  //animate from 0 to default size
  this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 1000, "bounce");
});
```

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/85VtZ/6/

Have fun ;)

Comment: very nice. do you have an API reference for gRaphael? the official website offers no documentation..