# Primefaces PIE chart animation

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, pie-chart

Is there any way to animate primefaces `PieChart`. I searched all attributes but unable to find that How Can I animate it? Actually I want that Chart should draw in slow motion. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: have you tried any of the following primefaces effects http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/effectsHome.jsf ?

Comment: thnx @Daniel I havn't tried them before.Now i use them and found that these effects are good but They didn't solve my problem because these it didn't draw circle but it effects the whole diagram.I mean that <piechart> draw a circle in a white square background and this effects is applied on that background on which circle is drawn.So when a load the page it shows not only the circle moving but the whole diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see , there is no animation in jqplot (which is being used by primefaces charts) pie charts [Pie chart Animation Issue #468 created 2011-11-22](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/468/pie-chart-animation)

As a workaround you can use [primefaces effects](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/effect.xhtml) , But it will affect the entire chart container...

You can always move on to some other third party charting library

---

There are no simple third party library's (they are simple but not compared to primefaces components) , you will have to write much more code, but the flexibility will be much bigger ,

For example [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) Pie [gRaphael Pie Chart : Add animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10823832/617373)

Or

[Fusion charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#pie-and-doughnut)

Comment: please recommend any other good and simple(same like primefaces) chart Library.