# Partially fill an SVG using Raphael JS, incrementally

Tags: svg, path, raphael, fill

New to using Raphael, and trying to find the best way to partially fill a path incrementally

basically the idea is, as you click on the button, the path fills incrementally and linear. (roughly 15-20% increments)

Been reading through Raphael documentation to see if there is some examples showing a good solution.

```
 var button1 = $('#button1');

 $(document).ready(function(){


 var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '300', '300');

var path_c = rsr.path("M168.846,131.616L56.634,196.404 c-35.78-61.978-14.546-141.216,47.424-176.996c20.639-11.915,40.961-17.36,64.787-17.36V131.616z"); 
path_c.attr({fill: '#000',stroke: '#000000',"stroke-width": '0',"stroke-miterlimit": '10',parent: 'group_a','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('id', 'path_c');


/* add a click handler */
button1.click(function(){

/* animate the shape  */


path_c.animate({fill:"red", "stroke-width": 1}, 2000);


}); 

});
```

Thanks for any help, suggestions.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/y36tv/)

Comment: Haven't used it, but I was wondering if http://g.raphaeljs.com/ could be of some use, using the pie chart functionality. Also this could be of some use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798909/graphael-pie-chart-add-animation maybe you could draw the segments and scale out from nothing when the segment is clicked ?

Comment: Ahh ok, this seems to suit more of my need. I will experiment with this. had no idea it existed. Thanks so much